# AppScript vs PostMan UrlFetchApp PUT syntax issue

Tags: google-apps-script, postman

The request works in Postman but not in the Google Script.
Please see image below.

[image]

I've spent over an hour researching and trying various things to no avail.
Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Try to change `headers -> contentType` to: 'Content-Type'. Because you has is as JSON format and not as an javascript object the UrlFetchApp does not covert to the standard: `Content-Type`.

Comment: @RemcoE33 No luck. But thank you anyway, Remco33!

Comment: Do you log the return response? What does it say? The http status code indicates that it is alright. And the payload is different. Yes / please change. Don't know if that matters

Comment: @RemcoE33 The response is the data it has and in this case it's showing 'yes/no' so that means it didn't apply the change that was requested. The change is swapping 'yes' with 'please change'.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.